# recording a value from cell when selecting an option from a listbox in excel

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am working with an excel document, where I have a listbox in one cell. when I select one option from the listbox, there is another cell which computes a value. I want to save this value in another cell. Is there any way by which this can be done without typing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally follow. Is this basically it?

You have a dropdown menu, which than is assigned a particular cell as a control (let's say A1). This cell stores an integer, which is the index of the item of the list you have selected. Based on this value, you want to do something to compute a value and put this in another cell. But I get lost about there.

Comment: Its basically like this. There is a dropdown list in a cell (say A1). Upon selection of an option from the list, a value is obtained in a cell(say A2). I need that value which is observed in A2 to be recorded in a cell (say A3). The A1 cell is dynamic and keeps changing and so do values in A2. I need to save the A2 data in different cells based on the options selected.